# Add table level Contraint that checks for date overlap in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, check-constraints

I have a table in Sql Server where i have Columns : UserId, RoleId, FromDate and Todate.
I want to write a contraint that check same RoleId and UserId are not present for the same date.

Thanks In Advance....

Comment: I think you should change your table structure.You don't have everyday in your table to put an Index on it.

Comment: Is `FromDate` constrained to only contain a *date* (with the time portion always set to midnight) or is it any general datetime value, but you need only a single entry for each day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have time portion or the time portion is the same in all records you can use `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE yourSchema.yourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueConstraint1 UNIQUE (RoleId, UserId, FromDate);
```

This way combination of date, RoleId and UserId can occur only once in table, other attempts to insert the same combination will fail.

Note that this will work if your date field has values for time portion that are the same in every record (for instance 0) or the data type of the field is `DATE` (which eliminates the time portion).

**If your date field has time portion that varies among records**, try one of this approaches:

A) Add computed column of definition

```
ALTER TABLE yourSchema.yourTable 
ADD constraintCheckDate AS CAST(FromDate AS DATE)
```

and add `UNIQUE` constraint of definition

```
ALTER TABLE yourSchema.yourTable 
ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueConstraint1 UNIQUE (RoleId, UserId, constraintCheckDate)
```

B) Use trigger to validate data before inserting it, data will be entered only if it doesn't already exist:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1 ON yourSchema.yourTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    yourSchema.yourTable t
        JOIN    inserted i ON 
                CAST(t.FromDate AS DATE) = CAST(i.FromDate AS DATE) 
        AND     t.RoleId =  i.RoleId 
        AND     t.UserId =  i.UserId
    )
        INSERT  yourTable(RoleId, UserId, FromDate, ToDate)
        SELECT  RoleId, UserId, FromDate, ToDate
        FROM    inserted
    ELSE
        RAISERROR('Error', 16, 0)

END
GO
```

Comment: The trigger works fine.. as same data is not inserted in the table. But it does not return a warning message... how can i do that...

Comment: You can call `RAISERROR` function with severity level 16 (enough to transfer the execution to the `CATCH` block). I added it to the answer.